# Appending directory name to each line when concatenating files from a nested structure

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a file tree that looks like this

```
03
├── 01
│   ├── File 1.csv   
└── 02
    ├── File 2.csv
04
├── 01
│   ├── File 1.csv 
└── 02
    ├── File 2.csv
05
├── 01
│   ├── File 1.csv
└── 02
    ├── File 2.csv
```

My goal is to use the folder names as dates ... e.g. `03/01`, `03/02` and so on..

for each date created I want to append that as a new column into each corresponding CSV.

Here's what I've tried so far..

```
for i in */*; do 
    na= echo "$i"; 
done | awk -F";" '{$(NF+1)=na OFS $(NF+1)}' */*/*.csv >> ../outer/output.csv
```

I have tried using awk but I know I'm missing something in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't refer to shell variables directly in an `awk` script. You can do `awk -v na=$i`

Comment: Probably more sensible to just pass all the filenames to awk on its command line, and have the awk script look at the name.

Comment: If you don't set `OFS` there won't be an additional column based on the field delimiter given (here semicolon).  Default one is space, not probably desired for ~ CSV format.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `for` loop. `awk` has a `FILENAME` variable that contains the current filename, you can extract the date part from that.

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" '{
    split(FILENAME, path, "/"); 
    $(NF+1) = path[1] "/" path[2]; 
    print
}' */*/*.csv >> ../outer/output.csv
```

Comment: Might invoke with `printf '%s\0' */*/*.csv | xargs -0 awk ...` or such to handle the case when the list of names (+ environment variables etc) is longer than ARG_MAX.

Comment: If you don't set `OFS` there won't be an additional column based on the delimiter given.  Or, `print $0 ";" path... ` where you can remove `FS` as well.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! However, it is not writing the new column as it should.. file is printing out the same as before... thx

Comment: It doesn't modify the original files, it goes into `output.csv`.

Comment: Yes, but the output.csv is unchanged from the original file.. The new column using the FILENAME information is not created..

Comment: I just tested it and it works. I was missing the `OFS` setting in the original code, so it was changing the field separator, but it was still working.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {sub("/[^/]+$","", FILENAME)} 
              {print $0 ";" FILENAME}' */*/*.csv >> ../outer/output.csv
```

Comment: Don't understand the down votes!  This should be working fine, I'll not be able to fix any deficiencies unless someone comments on it.

Comment: This did not work either.. file is left unchanged .. no new column added.

Comment: OK for debugging please try `awk '{print $0 ";" FILENAME}'  */*/*.csv`